# Toastr notification on failed form submit

Tags: laravel

I'm using toastr notification in my app. I send the notification when the form submit is failed due to validation or when the form submit is succeed. I usually do it this way :

```
public function store(Request $request) {
        $data = $request->all();
        $rules = [
            'name' => 'required|string',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'message' => 'required|string',
            'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|captcha',
        ];
        $validate = Validator::make($data, $rules);
        if ($validate->fails()) {
            $error = array(
                'message' => "Error sending the message!",
                'alert-type' => 'error'
            );
            return back()->withErrors($validate)->withInput()->with($error);
        }

        Feedback::create($data);
        $success = array(
            'message' => "Thanks for the feedback! Your message was sent successfully!",
            'alert-type' => 'success'
        );
        return redirect()->route('contactus')->with($success);
    }
```

But when the table columns number is large (10 columns or more) I'd like to use Form Request Class instead rather than declaring the rules in the store method. So it became like this :

```
public function store(FeedbackRequest $request) {
        $data = $request->all();

        Feedback::create($data);
        $success = array(
            'message' => "Thanks for the feedback! Your message was sent successfully!",
            'alert-type' => 'success'
        );
        return redirect()->route('contactus')->with($success);
    }
```

The problem is, when using Form Request I don't know how to send the error notification when validation fails. Is there a way to check if Form Request Class validation failed so I can send the error notification ? That's all and thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Adding After Hooks To Form Requests](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#creating-form-requests) is exactly what you need in your Request class:

```
public function withValidator($validator)
{
    $validator->after(function ($validator) {
        if ($validator->failed()) {
            $validator->errors()->add('field', 'Something is wrong with this field!'); // handle your new error message here
        }
    });
}
```